# Use another module's class inside a class definition

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I would like to reuse a class definition from another module, but I face the problem that while using module exports classes, these cannot be used in definitions other classes:
Main.psm1:

```
class M {
    [string] $someProperty
}
```

ClientModule.psm1:

```
using module Main
class C {
    [M] $mClass # this does not work
}
$mClass = [M]::new() # this works
```

Am I missing something? Can my goal be achieved in some other way? (I hope to avoid dot-sourcing)

Comment: Your code copypasted as is works for me in PS5.1. Are you sure `using module` is the first statement in your full script?

Comment: I figured this out, but I do not think it warrants an answer, since it was a rather stupid mistake: I also had a manifest file for M and forgot to uncomment RootModule=, which essentially turned M into an empty shell.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to try Inheritance such as

```
using module Main
Class C : M
{

}
```

A great reference for Powershell classes can be found at  https://xainey.github.io/2016/powershell-classes-and-concepts/#inheritance

Comment: If my script cannot find M, then I cannot inherit from M either.
Also, my goal is composition, not inheritance.